# Empty request sent when querying on NEST 5.0.0-rc1

Tags: nest

The problem is basically that no matter which query I'm building, it is never sent to elasticsearch.
For instance for this one:

```
_elasticClient.SearchAsync<CostSearch>(d =>
                d.Query(q =>
                    q.Match(f => f.Field(c => c.AgencyTrackingNo == costQuery.Query))
                )
            );
```

The request sent is an empty object, which means I'm getting all the values from that index and type.
You can check that on the following logs:

[11:47:36 INF] POST http://localhost:9200/costs/costsearch/_search
Request:
{}
Status: 200

```
{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0},"hit
s":{"total":1,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"costs","_type":"costsearch","_i
d":"1","_score":1.0,"_source":{
    "id": "-0897-98df7-df8-96",
    "title": "Test cost",
    "budget": 12323.34,
    "contentType": "Photo",
    "agencyTrackingNo": "GL036001V",
    "agencyProducer": "Grey, New York",
    "costOwner": "John Doe guid",
    "stage": "Draft",
    "approvalStatus": "ToBeApproved",
    "ioNumber": "IO123854B",
    "initiative": "Gillete 2016",
    "budgetRegion": "Japan",
    "country": "countryid",
    "city": "cityid",
    "userGroups": ["1987", "1986"]
}
}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, turns out I was misusing the Field selector.

```
_elasticClient.SearchAsync<CostSearch>(d =>
                d.Query(q =>
                    q.Match(f => f.Field(c => c.AgencyTrackingNo).Query(costQuery.Query))
                )
            );
```